# Non-Blocking Sleep in Vbs, while waiting for WScript.Shell

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm working with a VBS1, starting a `WScript.Shell`, starting another VBS2.

VBS1 is running in a bigger context and I need to keep that proccess running and working, while waiting for the result of my VBS2 (about 20-60sec)

Using `Sleep` is non-blocking in the script, but is blocking my proccess, so I need another option.

Here's the code I got so far:

```vb
strFinalCommand = "wscript.exe " & CStr(ScriptPath) & " " & CStr(strParams)
Set ObjShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ShellExec = ObjShell.Exec(strFinalCommand)

hitTimeout = False
SleepCounter = 0
Do While ShellExec.Status = 0 'WshRunning
    ActiveSession.Sleep 100   '--> On changing sleep-duration, please change multiplier in IF below, too
    SleepCounter = SleepCounter + 1
    If SleepCounter >= TimeoutDuration * 10 Then 'TimeoutDuration * 2
        hitTimeout = True
        ShellExec.Terminate
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Set ShellExec = Nothing
Set ObjShell = Nothing

If hitTimeout = False Then
    ReportSuccess = True
End If
```

Everything is running fine regarding that script, but other actions running the proccess are blocked.

Can anyone suggest another `Sleep`, which is non-blocking?

Comment: application.wait

Comment: @SivaprasathV VBScript doesn't support that.

Comment: My bad.....I code mostly in VBA....sorry

Comment: VBScript doesn't really support parallel execution. Launching worker processes is about the only way to do this. If you want to do other tasks in parallel, you probably need to launch additional worker processes. For further help please describe the actual problem you're having. What is being blocked, and how do you expect it to work?

Comment: remove activesession.sleep...keep the session in a active loop till the wsh closes...but it would reduce performance by a bit i guess...

Comment: Removing `ActiveSession.Sleep` is NOT recommended. Without it the script would consume 100% CPU spinning its wheels. It's sleeping 100 ms per iteration to yield the CPU to other processes that might need it. That should be just fine.